# How to enable animation of linked rigged object

Tags: animation, armature, linked-data

I made a simple stickman with joints. Works fine. Saved it as stickman.blend. I grouped CTRL+G the stickman+armature.

I made a new scene.blend file. I linked the group from the stickman with ctrl+alt+O into the scene. It is visible with all joints. So far so good. But I can not get it into Posemode. I think this is because it is "hard" linked to the stickman.blend. So I need a tip, how I can animate this in a new scene.

I don't want to simply append it to the scene, because when I make changes to the stickman they should also appear in my scene.

So for such a low level question. But after google/youtube I was out of an idea.

thanks for your help in advance

Comment: see [this DOC page about proxy object](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Template:Release_Notes/2.43/Animation/Proxy_Objects)

Comment: because you linked. you have to go back to the original and edit/pose it.

Comment: Thanks Chebhou, the linked document sheds light into this. CTRL+ALT+P was the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

you have to use the Proxy Objects :

> A proxy is a legal stand-in or substitute for the real thing. In Blender, when you make a linked copy (described above), you cannot edit the object; all you have is a link to it. You cannot add to it or change it, because its source is in another file that is not open.   [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/linked_libraries/library_proxies.html?#proxies)

to convert the linked object into a Proxy Object you select the linked Object and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> now you can animate the proxy object and it will get updated to the linked when you reload the file.